# How does a Java constant change?

Tags: java

I am learning Java right now and I am stumped on constants. It says in my book that they are good for declaring a variable that doesn't change. Example would be:

```
final double PI = 3.14159
```

How is this different from

```
double pi = 3.14159
```

How would "pi" change in a program?

Answer (score 5):

The `final` keyword makes a variable unchangeable. This means that you can initialize it and you will never be able to change it.

```
final double PI = 3.14159

PI = 2; //You are trying to change the value of a constant, this will result in a compile-time error
```

To change a variable's value, just re-assign a value to that variable:

```
double pi = 3.14159;

pi = 2; //pi is not a constant, so its value can be changed
```

Comment: Except in constructor.

Comment: @Nambari No, even in the constructor you can assign a value to a final variable once.

Comment: That is what I meant, your answer saying, "will never be able to change".

Comment: @Nambari I don't get the point. What's wrong with saying that a constant can be initialized and then it cannot be changed (re-initialized) anymore?

Comment: most of the times confusion occurs, that we have defined variable final, so we can't assign value. But if you have final instance variable defined, you can assign value to it in constructor, but not in methods. If instance final variable already has value, you can't assign another value in constructor. We are saying same, but words are different.

Comment: I think Jon Skeet can change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
final double PI = 3.14159
PI = 2; // Compile error

double pi = 3.14159
pi = 2; // Works fine
```

**Final** fields cannot be modified after they are initialized. They are initialized when the constructor is called, and keep their value for the rest of the object's lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can define `pi` as a standard `double`. In fact, if you're defining `PI` then it needs to be a `double` (or `BigDecimal` depending on your use).

The `final` keyword means this value will not change. It makes your code far more readable. Look at it like this:

```
final double PI = 3.14;

double a = Math.pow(PI * radius, 2);
```

You see how it's instantly obvious `PI` is the value you're using, as opposed to just `3.14` which can mean anything in any context?

Comment: double a = Math.pow(PI * radius, 2);

I understand this but you can still do this even if it was:

int pi = 3.14159

Comment: @CodyGilbert Not if it was an int, as 3.14159 is not an integer. But as a non-final double? Sure.

Answer (score 0):

[Read langugage spec jls #4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> A variable can be declared final. A final variable may only be assigned to once. Declaring a variable final can serve as useful documentation that its value will not change and can help avoid programming errors.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to declare a constant is to ensure that it cannot be changed. If in your code, you attempt to change its value, you'll get an error (I think, bit rusty on Java, to be honest)

While, off the top of my head, I can't think of a situation where a constant *couldn't* be declared as a variable, it makes the code clearer and prevents you or another coder from accidentally changing a value that shouldn't be changed.

Comment: How would it change though? Does the code/program change it or is it there so other people don't change your code?

Comment: @CodyGilbert You mean pi, the one that isn't declared as a constant?

Comment: No I mean the one that is declared as a constant. I understand you can either declare pi as normal or PI as a constant. But I just don't understand the reason. If I was to make a program and declare pi = 3.14159 then that is what pi means. If i was to make a program and clare PI = 3.14159 then that is what PI means. It can be used the same way in the entire program.

Comment: @CodyGilbert As I said, you could write pretty much every program that uses constants without using constants, and they should work the same way. However, by making the variable into a constant, it makes it clear that the value you have assigned to PI should never change, and reinforces that by causing an error if you try to change the value. That way, if someone (or just you, months later, having forgotten that the variable should stay constant) updates the code and tries to change the value of PI, they won't be able to.

Answer (score 0):

`final` means that value of variable can't be changed.

So the following code will not be accepted:

```
final double PI = 3.14159;
PI = 3.14;  //error because PI is declared as final
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of making it a constant, is so you or an other programmer don't change the value in error. It's not can Pi change it's declaring to the compiler/interpreter that any any attempt to change it, is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

once you discovered `anonymous inner class or method implementation\overriding` you will realize what your `final` variables are good for.

The basic means of `final` is to ensure the **reference of the object won't change** after object construction.

You can do something like this:

```
public class PI {
private double piValue;

public PI(double pi) {
this.piValue = pi;
}
public double getPi() { return piValue; }
public void setPi(double newPi) { piValue = newPi; }

}

//somewhere else 
final PI myPi = new PI(3.14159);
//but you can change it via setter;
myPi.setPi(3.13);
//but myPi reference wont change!!!
```